# Sudden memory spike while using an UIImage for CGContextSetFillColorWithColor

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, core-graphics

I am using an image to fill the color in the current graphics context using the following statement:

```
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(aContext,[[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:kRunnerGradientedBackgroundImage]] CGColor]);
```

This statement suddenly spikes my memory usage from 1.3 MB to 5.6 MB. If I release the `UIImage` object then it comes down to 1.3 MB but since retain count of image object is already 0, I cannot do this.

Any suggestions how to control this sudden memory spike?

Comment: hmm, `@autoreleasepool { YOUR CODE GOES HERE }` ?

Comment: autoreleasepool is also not helping. It keeps the memory at high value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed the image and now drawing the gradient using code. This reduced the memory spike by 4.5 MB.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern data has to be loaded into memory to use it.  No getting 'round that.  You could try a smaller pattern.  Also try setting the fill color for your context back to a simple solid color when you're done drawing with the pattern.

ADDED:  It's also possible that the graphics context itself becomes a lot bigger when you draw a pattern or image into it (to hold all the pixels required for the patterned image).  Try removing and releasing the UIView or CGLayer containing the graphics context.

Comment: Tried resetting the fill color back to [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor] but it does not help.

Answer (score 1):

How big is `kRunnerGradientedBackgroundImage` and what format is it in?  If PNG, does it have an unnecessary alpha channel?  As hotpaw2 mentioned, a pattern image should be as small as possible, which UIKit will then handle tiling or stretching for you.  Can you get the size down using [PNGCRUSH](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/)?

Another approach is to use `CGGradient` or `CAGradientLayer` to create your gradient programatically via CoreGraphics/CoreAnimation.

See:

- [CGGradient Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGradient/Reference/reference.html)
- [CAGradientLayer Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAGradientLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html)